# Немогу выполнить сразу несколько SQL запросов на php

Tags: php, sql

```
    $option_value        = $_POST['option_value'];
    $option_value_en     = $_POST['option_value_en'];
    $sql      = "
    UPDATE content SET  option_value='$option_value_en' WHERE option_id=1;
    UPDATE content SET  option_value='$option_value'    WHERE option_id=2;";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) { } else { }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Немогу выполнить сразу несколько SQL запросов на php. Ошибок не выдает, перезагружается страница, и контент не обновляется

Comment: Вы уверены, что никаких ошибок? В SQL нет символа ";". Сделайте одним запросом.

Comment: удостоверьтесь для начала, что драйвер БД который вы использует поддерживает выполнение нескольких запросов разом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE content 
SET option_value= CASE option_id WHEN 1 THEN '$option_value_en'
                                 WHEN 2 THEN '$option_value' 
                                 END
WHERE option_id IN (1, 2);
```